# Can't assign bash variable in python subprocess

Tags: python, bash, variables, subprocess, gnupg

I am trying to assign to a variable the fingerprint of a pgp key in a bash subprocess of a python script.
Here's a snippet:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
'''
    export KEYFINGERPRINT="$(gpg --with-colons --fingerprint --list-secret-keys | sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p')"
    echo "KEY FINGERPRINT IS: ${KEYFINGERPRINT}"
''',
shell=True, check=True,
executable='/bin/bash')
```

The code runs but echo shows an empty variable:
`KEY FINGERPRINT IS:` 
and if I try to use that variable for other commands I get the following error:
`gpg: key "" not found: Not found`

HOWEVER, if I run the same exact two lines of bash code in a bash script, everything works perfectly, and the variable is correctly assigned.

What is my python script missing?

Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the backslashes in your `sed` command. When you paste those into a Python string, python is escaping the backslashes. To fix this, simply add an `r` in  front of your string to make it a raw string:

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(
r'''
    export KEYFINGERPRINT="$(gpg --with-colons --fingerprint --list-secret-keys | sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p')"
    echo "KEY FINGERPRINT IS: ${KEYFINGERPRINT}"
''',
shell=True, check=True,
executable='/bin/bash')
```

Comment: Thank you, this solves it

Answer (score 0):

in order to run 2 commands in subprocess you need to run them one after each other or use `;`

```
import subprocess
ret = subprocess.run('export KEYFINGERPRINT="$(gpg --with-colons --fingerprint --list-secret-keys | sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p')"; echo "KEY FINGERPRINT IS: ${KEYFINGERPRINT}"', capture_output=True, shell=True)
print(ret.stdout.decode())
```

you can use `popen`:

```
commands = '''
    export KEYFINGERPRINT="$(gpg --with-colons --fingerprint --list-secret-keys | sed -n 's/^fpr:::::::::\([[:alnum:]]\+\):/\1/p')"
    echo "KEY FINGERPRINT IS: ${KEYFINGERPRINT}"
'''
process = subprocess.Popen('/bin/bash', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
out, err = process.communicate(commands)
print out
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to reply, but it still doesn't work. Also, I've been able to successfully execute multiple commands in other subprocesses without needing the `;`

Comment: try the edit one @rocky-evasive-dosage

Comment: still doesn't work. With `capture_output=True` no output is shown, so I tried to `touch` a file but it doesn't create.

Comment: try now @rocky-evasive-dosage

Comment: with subprocess I get `name 'ret' is not defined`.
with popen: `TypeError: memoryview: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Comment: now? @rocky-evasive-dosage

Comment: Now the variable is empty, same situation as explained in my original question. @Tal Folkman